# debugging vxworks loadModule failure

Tags: module, embedded, vxworks, loadmodule

I have a VxWorks Image Project project without a File-System on **MPC5200B**, using **DIAB** tool-chain.
I need to dynamically load a module from flash.

I allocated memory on my stack `char myTemporaryModuleData[MAX_MODULE_SIZE]`
and filled it with the module data from Flash.
(checked that the binary data is intact)

then i create a `memDevice('/mem/mem01', myTemporaryModuleData, moduleReadLength)`
open the psuedo-stream  `int fdModuleData = open("/mem/mem01", O_RDONLY, 777);`

when i run `int mId = loadModule(fdModuleData, LOAD_ALL_SYMBOLS);`
did not see anything in the console after running `loadModule();`
but `mId = 0` which indicates failure :(.
getErrno() returned 0x3D0004 (S_objLib_OBJ_TIMEOUT)

NOTE: it didn't take long at all to fail => timeout?

1. i tried replacing the module with a simple `void foo() { printf(...); }` module but still failes with same issue.
2. tried loading an `.out` instead of `.o`

unfortunately, nothing got me nowhere,
How can i know what caused it to fail? (log, last_error, anything i should check?)

Comment: What does `moduleShow()` shows after loading? You should be loading single `.o`s. I am not sure if device stream is usable in this way. You can try to create a file stream with `int fd = creat("myFile", 2)`. Then write the contents of your module by `write`. Finally load the module with `loadModule(fd, LOAD_ALL_SYMBOLS)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT.
Apparently, it was a mistake in the data read from the flash.

What I can contribute is that 'loadModule()' from memDrv device is possible and working.